# ¿Cómo puedo refrescar una página utilizando Flask?

Tags: html, python, aplicación-web, flask

estaba realizando un proyecto, y necesito que cada X segundos el contenido de mi index.html se actualice. Estoy utilizando Flask para el despliegue de la página web. Si me pudieran dejar un ejemplo muy sencillo de como realizarlo estaría muy agradecido.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el protocolo HTTP las peticiones siempre se inician desde el lado cliente. Por tanto no puedes hacer que un servidor como Flask "inicie" por sí solo un refresco de la página en un cliente. Lo que tienes que hacer entonces es forzar a que el navegador vuelva a pedirle la página a Flask cada X segundos.

Esto puedes lograrlo de dos formas:

- Añadiendo un poco de código JavaScript a la página (como parte del contenido que Flask le sirve). Ese código instalaría un temporizador que cada X segundos ejecutaría una función que haría `location.reload();`, lo que recargaría la página. Por ejemplo, el siguiente código lo haría cada 30 segundos:

  ```js
  <script>
  setTimeout(function(){
     window.location.reload(1);
  }, 30000);
  </script>
  ```
- Sin necesidad de JavaScript, haciendo que el HTML enviado por Flask contenga una cabecera que diga, por ejemplo para refrescar cada 30s:

  ```html
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
  ```

Además de estas soluciones, que son las más simples, también existen tecnologías como Server Sent Events (SSE) o WebSockets, que permiten establecer un canal entre cliente y servidor por el que el servidor puede enviar al cliente datos de forma asíncrona, al margen de las peticiones HTTP. Podrías usar uno de estos mecanismos para que el servidor envíe al cliente un aviso de que hay versión nueva de la página, para que éste la cargue. Esta solución es bastante más compleja, tanto desde el lado Flask (aunque hay librerías para SSE y para websockets son complejas) como desde el lado cliente, que requeriría programación en JavaScript para procesar los eventos que ocurren cada vez que el servidor envía notificaciones.

Comment: No creo que sea muy bonito estar navegando por la página y cada 30 segundos se recargue todo. Lo ideal sería utilizar ajax (lo más sencillo) o se puede usar alguna librería como React, Vue o Angular. Esto permite actualizar una o varias  secciones de la página sin tener que recargarla

Comment: Si veo que la solución no queda bien haciendo los refrescos probaré AJAX. Muchas gracias a los dos. :)